# On Change Event on working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I click on the single checkbox, it changes and green colored. But when I check Full day, all checkboxes are checked but color not change. also after checking full Day, I uncheck all times still full day is checked. I'm stuck, what wrong with this code?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('input:checkbox[name="time"]').change(function() {
    $('input:checkbox[name="time"]:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("active");
    $('input:checkbox[name="time"]:checked').parent().addClass("active");
  });
});

function selectAll(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('time');
  for (var i in checkboxes)
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
}
```

```css
.timing {
  width: 500px;
}

.timing label {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.timing label input {
  display: block;
}

.timing label.active {
  background-color: rgba(0, 204, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timing">
  <label for="11:30"><input name="time" class="timess" value="11:30" id="11:30" type="checkbox">11:30</label>
  <label for="12:00"><input name="time" class="timess" value="12:00" id="12:00" type="checkbox">12:00</label>
  <label for="12:30" class=""><input name="time" class="timess" value="12:30" id="12:30" type="checkbox">12:30</label>
</div>



<label for="selectall"><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" onClick="selectAll(this)" />Full Day</label>

<script>
  function selectAll(source) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('time');
    for (var i in checkboxes)
      checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added trigger event. Change event will not get fired if you check checkbox using JS.

```
function selectAll(source) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('time');
    for(var i in checkboxes)
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        $('input:checkbox[name="time"]').trigger('change');//Trigger change event to checkbox
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 
 
 $('input:checkbox[name="time"]').change(function () {
        $('input:checkbox[name="time"]:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("active");
        $('input:checkbox[name="time"]:checked').parent().addClass("active");
    });    
});

function selectAll(source) {
 checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('time');
 for(var i in checkboxes)
  checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        $('input:checkbox[name="time"]').trigger('change')
}
```

```css
.timing{width:500px;}
.timing label{width:100px;display:inline-block;border:1px solid #ccc;padding:10px;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;}
.timing label input{display:block;}
.timing label.active{background-color:rgba(0,204,0,1);}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timing">
<label for="11:30"><input name="time" class="timess" value="11:30" id="11:30" type="checkbox">11:30</label>
<label for="12:00"><input name="time" class="timess" value="12:00" id="12:00" type="checkbox">12:00</label>
<label for="12:30" class=""><input name="time" class="timess" value="12:30" id="12:30" type="checkbox">12:30</label>
</div>



<label for="selectall"><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" onClick="selectAll(this)" />Full Day</label>

<script>
function selectAll(source) {
 checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('time');
 for(var i in checkboxes)
  checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I would suggest to add curly braces around the for loop. At least correcting the intendation in the first code snippet, as it now visually suggests that `trigger` is called on every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is because you need to trigger a `change` event on the checkboxes when clicking the 'Select All' option so that their own event handler runs and changes their background colour. This does not occur when setting the `checked` state manually, so you can use the `trigger()` method in your code.

You should note though, that you can improve your logic by using `toggleClass()` and also removing the `on*` event attribute as they are outdated. Use an unobtrusive event handler as you do for the normal checkboxes. Try this:

```js
$('input:checkbox[name="time"]').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('label').toggleClass('active', this.checked);
});

$('#selectall').change(function() {
  $('input:checkbox[name="time"]').prop('checked', this.checked).trigger('change');
});
```

```css
.timing {
  width: 500px;
}

.timing label {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.timing label input {
  display: block;
}

.timing label.active {
  background-color: rgba(0, 204, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timing">
  <label for="11:30">
    <input name="time" class="timess" value="11:30" id="11:30" type="checkbox">
    11:30
  </label>
  <label for="12:00">
    <input name="time" class="timess" value="12:00" id="12:00" type="checkbox">
    12:00
  </label>
  <label for="12:30">
    <input name="time" class="timess" value="12:30" id="12:30" type="checkbox">
    12:30
  </label>
</div>

<label for="selectall">
  <input type="checkbox" id="selectall" />
  Full Day
</label>
```

Comment: Appreciate answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger the change function inside the loop

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:checkbox[name="time"]').change(function() {
    $('input:checkbox[name="time"]').parent().removeClass("active");
    $('input:checkbox[name="time"]:checked').parent().addClass("active");
  });
});

function selectAll(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('time');
  for (var i in checkboxes){
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    $('input:checkbox[name="time"]').trigger('change')
    }
}
```

```css
.timing {
  width: 500px;
}

.timing label {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.timing label input {
  display: block;
}

.timing label.active {
  background-color: rgba(0, 204, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timing">
  <label for="11:30"><input name="time" class="timess" value="11:30" id="11:30" type="checkbox">11:30</label>
  <label for="12:00"><input name="time" class="timess" value="12:00" id="12:00" type="checkbox">12:00</label>
  <label for="12:30" class=""><input name="time" class="timess" value="12:30" id="12:30" type="checkbox">12:30</label>
</div>



<label for="selectall"><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" onClick="selectAll(this)" />Full Day</label>
```